# $\text{Im}(S+T) \subseteq \text{Im}(S) + \text{Im}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

We are given two linear transformations - $S,T : V \to V$.

how do I prove that $\text{Im}(S+T) \subseteq \text{Im}(S) + \text{Im}(T)$?

Comment: It follows immediately from the fact that $(S+T)(v)=S(v)+T(v)$.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the definitions:
$$\operatorname{im}(S+T) = \{ Sv + Tv\, :\, v \in V \}$$
$$\operatorname{im} S + \operatorname{im} T = \{ Sv + Tw\, :\, v \in V,\ w \in V \}$$
Is it clearer now why $\operatorname{im}(S+T)$ is a subspace of $\operatorname{im} S + \operatorname{im} T$?

*Note: it's better to say 'is a subspace of' than 'is smaller than or equal to'. That's what the $\le$ sign means in this context.*